# Use merge sort to sort a list with only swap and rotation and one another list

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

I have two list : list A containing a set of random numbers and list B empty. I have to sort the list A.

I can make limited operations on these two lists like :

- move the first element of list A or B at the beginning of the list B or A
- swap the two first elements of list A or B like `32 41 8 9` become `41 32 8 9`
- make the last element of list A or B become the first in this list (rotation) like `32 41 8 9` become `9 32 41 8`
- make the first element of list A or B become the last one in this list (rotation) like `32 41 8 9` become `41 8 9 32`

I have already set up an algorithm to sort the list A using the list B as the stack and the set of allowed operations, but it takes time when the list becomes large (more than 1000 elements) and is therefore not performing at all.

So I looked on the side of the merge sort which is very nice for its performance with the linked lists that I use.

The problem is that the use of this one needs to cut lists into other sublists, but in my case I have the right only has two lists and the operations that I explained.

Is it possible to make a effective merge sort according to the guidelines? How to make this algorithm?

Comment: You know there's a difference between swapping the first and last element and swapping them... You should define whether you're talking about swapping two elements in a circular list or rotating a list, which would mean moving **all** elements in the list.

Comment: @Paul I have updated my message, thanks

Comment: You don't list any logic among the operations available, nor any operations for maintaining auxiliary storage.  If you have auxiliary storage and can perform arbitrary logic, then the operations you describe are sufficient to perform a merge sort.  If your alternatives are more limited, on the other hand, then you have not provided enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @HectorHansen I'd highly recommend you use Bubble-Sort for a simple reason: your data-structure doesn't provide RAM-behavior. You can of course emulate swaps between random positions in the list and other RAM-behavior, but the inefficiency that is caused by this can't be compensated by any algorithm, as efficient as it might be. Bubble-Sort would require `O(n ^ 2)` swaps and same amount of rotations. I'm dreaded by the thought of calculating the complexity of Merge-Sort in these terms. Merge-Sort is just extremely complicated to implement and even slower than Bubble-Sort here!!!

Comment: It's a bit late, I'll post sample-implementations of both algorithms tomorrow.

Comment: @Paul Why linked list isn't not optimized for merge sort ? And how I can use bubblesort with the best time complexity ?